# Importing CSV File to Google Maps

Tags: csv, maps, coordinates, kml

I have an quite big CSv File I want to have in Google Maps or just on a map. These are just coordinates but I have 600.000 of them..

Do you have any Idea how I can do this?

I've added an screenshot from XTabulator below:
[image: csv file]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is generate a KML file (see http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/csvtokml.html for a possible solution). You can then open that up in Google Maps by storing it online and linking to it from Google Maps as described at http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/whatiskml.html

EDIT: http://www.gpsbabel.org/ may let you do it without coding.

Comment: I don't have any experience with python, could you explain the process in detail? Or is there any software to do this easily?

Comment: You're going to need some coding to do that with most of the KML libraries out there: http://www.gpsbabel.org/ is one option that may let you do it with a UI.

Answer (score 15):

We have now (jan2017) a csv layer import inside Google Maps itself.[image]

Google Maps > "Your Places" > "Open in My Maps"

Comment: Sweet; this is pretty awesome.

Comment: does this still exists?

Comment: yes,  eddy147. it does exist

Answer (score 8):

GPS Visualizer has an interface by which you can cut and paste a CSV file and convert it to kml:

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/map_input?form=googleearth

Then use Google Earth. If you don't have Google Earth and want to display it online I found another nifty service that will plot kml files online:

http://display-kml.appspot.com/

Answer (score 6):

none of that needed....  just go to:

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/

now and load your csv file as-is.  extra columns and all.  it will slice and dice and use just the log & lat columns and plot it for you on google maps.

Answer (score 1):

For generating the KML file from your CSV file (or XLS), you can use [MyGeodata online GIS Data Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu). Here is the [CSV to KML How-To](http://howto.mygeodata.eu/#TXT).